# Real time Log mechanism while importing large files with blazor server app

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, blazor

I m using blazor server app and  importing large files. During import operation service will be logged errors and warnings. Users want me to show logs real time.Should I use Signal-R. Because I needed updates one way.

Comment: We solved it using Azure SignalR. The reason for using the Azure service was that we can easily run more than one instance of our server.

Comment: we dont need more than one instance. So is signal r  the best choise?

Comment: There's typically no absolute "best choice" but I would use SignalR, yes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: For sure SignalR is the option here to go.

Comment: SignalR is the easiest way to do this